# Avoiding static variables and use a clear design way to code

Tags: java, static-members

Consider the following three classes -

```
Class A
{

    static DrMag drmag; //Avoid static variables


    public DrMag validateCheck()
    {
        drmag.setName("Kane");
        drmag.setType("Student");
        drmag.setMarks(100);

        return drmag;
    }

    public void saveState()
    {
        if(drmag != null)
        {
            //do something usefull
            log.info("GREAT! drmag is not null");
        }
        else
        {
            log.info("OOPS! drmag is null");
        }

    }

}


class B
{
    A a = new A();

    DrMag drmag = a.validateCheck();

}

class C
{
    A a = new A();

    a.saveState();

}
```

The above are the three basic classes named as A, B and C.

First B is called that initializes `drmag` and then C is called that checks the value of `drmag`.

If the `drmag` is static then eveything is fine and I gets the output - "GREAT! drmag is not null".

If the drmag is not static then I get the output - "OOPS! drmag is null".

This is as expected because we are creating a new objects of A in both classes B and C.

But keeping a variable as static is not considered as good.

So one way is to make getter and setter methods in class A for variable `drmag` and set variable drmag at call from B and then get `drmag` variable at call from C.
However this still is giving the output - "OOPS! drmag is null".

The other way I thought is to create a constructor of class C and call it from class B where we can initialize `drmag` like -

```
class B
{
    A a = new A();
    DrMag drmag = a.validateCheck();
    C c = new C(drmag); //this will call constructor of class C and initialize `drmag`.     
}


class C
{
    DrMag drmag;

    public C(DrMag drmag)
    {
        this.drmag = drmag;
    }

    A a = new A();

    a.saveState(drmag);
}

class A
{
    DrMag drmag;


    public DrMag validateCheck()
    {
        drmag = new DrMag();
        drmag.setName("Kane");
        drmag.setType("Student");
        drmag.setMarks(100);

        return drmag;
    }

    public void saveState(DrMag drmag)
    {
        if(drmag != null)
        {
            //do something usefull
            log.info("GREAT! drmag is not null");
        }
        else
        {
            log.info("OOPS! drmag is null");
        }

    }
}
```

This design again has a flaw and looks complex.

Is there any clear way to deal this situation without using `static` ?

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish with the `drmag` variable?  For what reason did you decide that it needed to be static?

Comment: DrMag is a class that contains some fields like name, students, marks. So method `validateCheck()` is doing the same that it assigns values for name, students and marks and then returns `drmag`. I decided that it should be static because without it being static, the output is always - "OOPS! drmag is null". The reason is explained in the question.

Comment: I'm still confused.  What you're describing is `DrMag` is an object that contains data; something like a bean, right?  Is there any reason why you felt that it needed to be static?  I suppose the real question is, where are you putting the data in this bean, and why can't you just pass the instance of `DrMag` to your `validateCheck` method?

Comment: yes `DrMag` is a bean class simply a pojo and is not static. What is static is a declaration - `static DrMag drmag;` in class A so that `drmag` will have a class scope. Then when I call `saveState` from class C then it will not be null. The bean data is in the postgresql table and `validateCheck()` is just a method that is using that table to load the drmag.

Comment: I suppose I'll be more direct.  Why do you feel the need to put a pojo as a field to `A`?  Why can't you just pass it in?  Why did you make this decision?  What were you hoping to gain from it?  This question doesn't seem like it's answerable if we don't understand the intent (that is, what you want to happen without really explaining the code).

Comment: sorry if I haven't explained you enough that it isn't understandable. My point to put `drmag` as a field to `A` is to make it accessible as global class variable by putting static with class scope. So I called from class B and `drmag` was set with values. Then I used the same values which were set from class B to be used in class C. It is just like values of `drmag` which were set from class B are dependent and to be used from class C. That is only possible by global scope of `drmag`. Any other possibility to do the same then please welcome.

Comment: Your code snippets above do not compile. You claim that "First B is called that initializes drmag" but there is no code in B that initializes `drmag` in the first code snippet.

Comment: @MyGod making things globally available is generally something that you should **avoid**: it makes the code untestable, tightly coupled to global state, thread-unsafe, and hard to evolve. Pass objects around instead. Keep reference to objects in local variables, or in fields of local objects. In your second snippet, the first method creates and returns a DrMag, and the second method takes one as argument. There is no reason to keep a reference to the created DrMag in a field. The caller should keep the reference.

Comment: @davmac I used `DrMag drmag = a.validateCheck();` in B that returns the `drmag`.

Comment: Also, it's pretty hard to tell you how to design code without knowing what the code should do in the first place, and when all we have is meaningless class and method names, and uncompilable code.

Comment: @JBNizet It will help if you please share some code snippet for the same.

Comment: Start by explaining what the code **should** do.

Comment: @MyGod Yes you used 'DrMag = a.validateCheck()' in B, but in the code you have given this method would simply throw a `NullPointerException`. You need to provide actual, compilable code that actually exhibits the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @davmac Try the second code snippet as that is what I implemented without static and so is more according to given scenario of "don't use statics".

Comment: @MyGod it is up to YOU to fix your question. It is YOUR responsibility to make sure the code is relevant to the question. You should edit the code and/or question so that this is the case. The second code snippet does not compile, there is a statement in class C that needs to be inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields are not necessarily evil. They exist in all OO languages and they have sense for anything that is related to the whole class.

They are frowned upon because they can be used for data related to a bunch of objects and that can lead to problem. For example, you use a class `Student` to manage students of a class. The name of the school is constant and could be a static field. But what if you want later to extend the application and want to manage different schools.

When using a static field, you should simply wander if *functionaly* it is not a field of another class that would have a 1-n relation to your present class.

It is rather broad for a question on SO, and I'll only give clues to solve your problem. a detailed explaination would be way too long - but this is always much too long for a comment.